# Using Cucmber to run test scenarios and generate JVM reports as Java Application

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I am trying to build a java application which replicates the functionality of cucumber after I execute the command `mvn clean install`.
Currently after doing `mvn clean install`, cucumber executes all scenarios and creates JVM report in a specified directory.
But rather than doing `mvn clean install` I want to replicate exact same features by running my application jar.(Main method in java application jar should call cucumber classes and methods to execute test scenarios and generate report)

Following are pom.xml and class definitions which I am using to run test scenarios and generate test report using  `mvn clean install`

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>hellocucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>hellocucumber</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <cucumber.version>6.8.1</cucumber.version>
    <junit.version>4.13</junit.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
  <plugins>  
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>package-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.example.mainclass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
        
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
         <version>3.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>execution</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <projectName>cucumber-jvm-example</projectName>
              <!-- this is similar report as jenkins report -->
              <outputDirectory>AllReports/cucumber-JVM-reports</outputDirectory>
               <!-- to generate better report-similar to Jenkin report,maven-cucumber-reporting plug-in is used,which reads the generated cucumber.json file in local directory and generates cucumber-JVM-reports -->
              <cucumberOutput>AllReports/report.json</cucumberOutput>
              <skippedFails>true</skippedFails>
              <enableFlashCharts>false</enableFlashCharts>
              <buildNumber>42</buildNumber>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

RunCucumberTest.java

```
package hellocucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
plugin = {"pretty", "html:AllReports/cucumber-html-report",
          "json:AllReports/report.json", "junit:AllReports/cucumber.xml"},
features = "testcases/features")
public class RunCucumberTest {  
}
```

StepDefinitions.java

```
package hellocucumber;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

class IsItFriday {
    static String isItFriday(String today) {
        return "Friday".equals(today) ? "TGIF" : "Nope";
    }
}

public class StepDefinitions {
    private String today;
    private String actualAnswer;

    @Given("today is {string}")
    public void today_is(String today) {
        this.today = today;
    }

    @When("I ask whether it's Friday yet")
    public void i_ask_whether_it_s_Friday_yet() {
        actualAnswer = IsItFriday.isItFriday(today);
    }

    @Then("I should be told {string}")
    public void i_should_be_told(String expectedAnswer) {
        assertEquals(expectedAnswer, actualAnswer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber core comes with a [Commandline interface](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?sbsearch=mvn%20exec%3A#running-cucumber). For usage instructions use:

```
mvn exec:java                                  \
    -Dexec.classpathScope=test                 \
    -Dexec.mainClass=io.cucumber.core.cli.Main \
    -Dexec.args="--help"
```

Or a main method:

```
import io.cucumber.core.cli.Main;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte status = Main.run("--help");
        System.exit(status);
    }

}
```